# Can't login to ubuntu after upgrading to 22.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I have two users. I can't login to the user where I did the upgrade from. I can login to other users. Whenever I enter the password I am shown the login screen again.

Logging in to another user works, but can't update:

https://ibb.co/D5bTMJc

This is what my /etc/apt/sources.list looks like:

````
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy universe
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://al.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
# deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe```
````

Comment: Can you login on the console? Do you see any output there? You may have written some files with root rights, which would usually be written with user rights on the login. Such things can cause weird issues. A first start is to test if login on the console works and from there you can also try to fix things.

Comment: I can login from the console. I just can't login through GUI.

Comment: do you have a `.xsession-errors` file in the home directory? Maybe it contains some helpful error messages.

Comment: Nope. No .xsession-erros file at all. I'm really clueless at this point.

Comment: Try `find \! -uid $UID` to list files not owned by the current user. Creating files as the wrong user can be a side-effect of using su/sudo and some programs don't react well when they cannot write a file that should be writable.

Comment: I ran the command but it listed many many files. I didn't create anything. This happened right after I upgraded my Ubuntu to 22.04.1. In the end, the upgrade said it failed, but after restarting the system I'm stuck in the login loop.

Comment: Okay. I fixed the login loop by changing the option from Wayland to Ubuntu X-Org in the login screen. Now I can log in but I can't update packages. It shows the error in the screenshot. Any idea why that might occur?